# Angular service does not work with REST API

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript

In my application I have the following template:

```
<div class="skills-filter-input" ng-class="{'hidden-xs': skillsFilterHidden}">
<input type="text" ng-model="skillQuery" ng-change="filterSkills()" placeholder="Filter skills" class="filter-input"/>
```

The `CoffeeScript` of `filterSkills()` method is as follow:

```
$scope.filterSkills = ->
    $scope.skills = SkillsService.filterByName($scope.skillQuery)
    console.log "Query: " + $scope.skillQuery
    console.log "Skills: " + $scope.skills.length
```

When I am typing skill name to filter the result I can only see the Loading.. statement, I noticed that `$scope.skills.length` is empty even when I typed skill which exists in database, so what is wrong with the following `SkillService` or maybe the bug is somewhere else?

```
angular.module("myModule").service("SkillsService", ["$resource", ($resource)      ->
class SkillsService

constructor: ->
  @skills = angular.element("skills").data("json")
  @skills.$resolved = true
  @endPoint = $resource("/skills")

all: ->
  @skills

skillForId: (id) ->
  _.find(@all(), (skill) ->
    skill.id == id
  )

skillForIds: (ids) ->
  _.map(ids, (id) =>
    @skillForId(id)
  )

filterByName: (name) ->
  @endPoint.query(query: name).$promise

  new SkillsService()

])
```

EDITED:
in my logs on server side I can see this:
`Started GET "/skills?0=m&1=s&2=f&3=t"`
but the request should look like this: `/skills?query=msft`

EDITED 2:

```
  (function() {
  angular.module("myModule").service("SkillsService", [
"$resource", function($resource) {
  var SkillsService;
  SkillsService = (function() {
    function SkillsService() {
      this.skills = angular.element("skills").data("json");
      this.skills.$resolved = true;
      this.endPoint = $resource("/skills");
    }

    SkillsService.prototype.all = function() {
      return this.skills;
    };

    SkillsService.prototype.skillForId = function(id) {
      return _.find(this.all(), function(skill) {
        return skill.id === id;
      });
    };

    SkillsService.prototype.skillForIds = function(ids) {
      return _.map(ids, (function(_this) {
        return function(id) {
          return _this.skillForId(id);
        };
      })(this));
    };

    SkillsService.prototype.filterByName = function(name) {
      this.endPoint.query({
        query: name
      }).$promise;
    };

    return SkillsService;

  })();
  return new SkillsService();
}
]);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Can you please post the transpiled JavaScript?

Comment: I am not coffeescript guy but it seems `@endPoint.query(query: name)` is translated to `@endPoint.query(name)`.

Comment: @AndyGaskell here it is, I think that the problem is related to my EDITED #1 text

Comment: What happens if you hardcode `query: 'msft'` in `filterByName`?

Answer (score 0):

I built a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHNWlb0IVFkah8CgjJm4?p=preview). The SkillService constructor was throwing exceptions; you shouldn't be referencing the DOM in a controller, let alone a service. When I commented out the first two lines of the constructor it worked insofar as the correct HTTP request was made.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).controller('myController', function($scope, $resource, SkillsService) {
  $scope.endPoint = $resource('/skills');
  $scope.endPoint.query({query: 'msft'});
  SkillsService.filterByName('msft');
});

 (function() {
  angular.module("myApp").service("SkillsService", [
"$resource", function($resource) {
  var SkillsService;
  SkillsService = (function() {
    function SkillsService() {
      //this.skills = angular.element("skills").data("json");
      //this.skills.$resolved = true;
      this.endPoint = $resource("/skills");
    }

    SkillsService.prototype.all = function() {
      return this.skills;
    };

    SkillsService.prototype.skillForId = function(id) {
      return _.find(this.all(), function(skill) {
        return skill.id === id;
      });
    };

    SkillsService.prototype.skillForIds = function(ids) {
      return _.map(ids, (function(_this) {
        return function(id) {
          return _this.skillForId(id);
        };
      })(this));
    };

    SkillsService.prototype.filterByName = function(name) {
      this.endPoint.query({
        query: name
      }).$promise;
    };

    return SkillsService;

  })();
  return new SkillsService();
}
]);

}).call(this);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.2" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{hi}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: how to check if your plunker is working with my API endpoint? cause when I typed its address in the $resource it does not take any effect

Comment: after your changes there is no `skills` variable so how it is suppose to work? have you tested it?